# Azure cognitive search services : Semantic search Error :Verification code expired before contacting the server

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Failed to reset indexer "........", error: "Error with data source: Verification code expired before contacting the server  Please adjust your data source definition in order to proceed.

We are getting this error each time I tried to run indexer / after some time it starts indexing

Comment: What is your data source ? what authentication mechanism  are you using RBAC/SAS ?

Comment: @Jdresc data source: sharepoint, SAS. First time when we created the indexes, it was showing me a login url and verification code and it worked fine.But after few days I want to rerun my indexes, but this time, it is not showing me the verification code.instead it just shows "verification code expired..."